# .change() jquery event not working on dynamically created input elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having a input of type = " file " on my page. Also I have a button "Add Inputs" on the page which adds a new file input element on page and I want to run a function when user changes the value of any of those inputs by selecting a new file.
Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="InpDiv">
        <input type="file" name="fname">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="addInp()">Add Inputs</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Function that is going to run after change in file input.

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='fname']").each(function(){
            $(this).change(function(){
                alert('hello');
                
                // Do some work here.

            });
        });
    });


// Function that adds new file inputs.

    function addInp()
    {
        $('#InpDiv').clone().appendTo(".main");
    }
```

Now the problem is .change() method works fine for those inputs which were present already on page but not works *(won't prompt "hello" message here)* on change of values in those newly created inputs. I made more than one file inputs already present on page and .change() worked for all of them but it didn't worked for any of the newly created inputs.

**Is it so that events won't work with dynamically added elements on page ?
And if so then how am I going to get this work done?**

Comment: Make the change callback function into a named function (instead of anonymous) and apply the change event on the cloned element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try delegation approach using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/). This will ensure that events will be attached to all the elements that are added to the DOM at a later time.

Also I will prefer using *input* event instead of *change*:

Change:

```
$(this).change(function(){
```

To:

```
$('.main').on('input', this, function(){
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='fname']").each(function(){
      $('.main').on('input', this, function(){
          alert('hello');

          // Do some work here.

      });
  });
});


// Function that adds new file inputs.

function addInp()
{
  $('#InpDiv').clone().appendTo(".main");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div id="InpDiv">
        <input type="file" name="fname">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="addInp()">Add Inputs</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. I guess I should have posted the question earlier. It could have saved my few hours which I wasted to figure why that .change() was not working.

Comment: One more doubt. So should I also prefer using .on('click' , myFunction) instead of . click () method ?

Comment: @Avi, yes, you should use that to be on the safe side.:)

Comment: @Mamun `.click()` is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`. Why would the latter be safer?

Comment: @Ivar, didn't notice that, I mean the delegation approach...`.on( "click", this, handler )`:)